# How can I change this regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z]).{6,}$/
```

At the moment it checks at least 1 number and at least one letter present.

How can I make it at least one number and at least 1 upper case letter??

Thanks all.

Comment: “At the moment it checks at least 1 number and at least one letter present.” Well, it does plenty more than that. What’s the context? Also, regular expression syntax varies wildly from application to application. What program or library are you writing for? (Perl?)

Comment: javascript, sorry for not including.

Comment: @bdesham "Well, it does plenty more than that." indeed, lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part that matches the letter is `[A-Za-z]`. This is a character class, signified by the square brackets, meaning that it will match any single character specified inside the brackets. In this case, it will match any uppercase letter (`A-Z`) or lowercase letter (`a-z`). To make it match uppercase letters only, simply remove the lowercase part so it looks like this: `[A-Z]`.